# I have Php GD imagecreate issues

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have been developing codeigniter3.0 website now.

I use mpdf library.

I am gonna generate pdf from html view.

But I have one issue.

html view include Image.

when generate pdf form this page, this operation is run well on local server.

but On hosting server, below error is occured..

`mPDF error: IMAGE Error (http://xxxx.com/image.png): Error parsing image file - image type not recognised, and not supported by GD imagecreate`

Local's sever and hosting server are windows server and runs on Xampp with same version.
I used below code for generate pdf

```
$this->load->library('m_pdf');

$pdfObj = $this->m_pdf->pdf;

$htmlBody = $this->load->view('****/****.html', $reportData, true);
$htmlBody = mb_convert_encoding($htmlBody, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
//echo $htmlBody;
$pdfObj->WriteHTML($htmlBody);      
// Store In Server.
$pdfObj->Output($filePath, "F");
```

Html view is below

```
<div class="header"> 
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><img src='http://xxxx.com/image.png' class='clsImgCompanyLogo'></td>
        <td class="clsTDHeaderAddress">

        </td>           
        <td class="clsTDHeaderContact">

        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>     
</div>
```

......
Please help me

Comment: can you doubecheck phpinfo() for both server , may be some extension not enabled.

Comment: correctly wich extenstion?

Comment: Thank you,But correctly wich extenstion? I already check. and i install same xampp tool on local and sever.

Comment: ;extension=php_gd2.dll

remove ; from php.ini

Comment: Already ";" is removed on server's php.ini.

Comment: extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
....

Comment: which image type of image your pdf contains ? I mean gif,png or what ?

Comment: Png and Jpg files. but all image case occur error on server, and run on local.

Comment: Hi,Jd. i find issue cause. if we use "http://localhost/..xxx.png" on sever, then runs.But we use "http://example.com/xxx.png", tehnruns with error.how to fix this url error?

Comment: please check your base url for code igniter

Comment: which url's formart is right?